# Find only rows that contains "NaN" in a specific column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

How can i find only rows that contains "NaN" in a specific column ?

I tried this specific code to merge (left join) two dataFrame and find **ONLY** rows that contains "NaN" in "matricule"'s column.

```
ln []: import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

ln []: vehicule_xls = pd.read_excel("vehicule.xls")
vehicule_xls

ln []: vehicule_sql = pd.read_sql_query('select * from vehicule ', con=engine)
vehicule_sql

ln []: vehicules = pd.merge(vehicule_xls, vehicule_sql, left_on='Immat', right_on="matricule", how='left', indicator='Indicator')

ln []: vehicules[vehicules['matricule'].isnull()]
```

But i got this error on the last command.

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Comment: would be useful to know which line generates the error

Comment: le last one "ln []: vehicules[vehicules['matricule'].isnull()]"

Comment: you need to post raw data that reproduces this, also what does `vehicules.info()` show

Comment: all column are non-null object. 
it's a left join (when i merged two dataframes). So i have "nan" in vehicule_sql columns values.

Comment: I just want to find the difference between two dataframes.

Comment: Does `pd.isnull(...)` work any better?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a binary vector indicating whether a specific row has a `nan` in the column of interest as follows

```
fltr = vehicules['matricule'].isnull()
```

You can then extract the subset of interest with

```
subset = vehicules[fltr]
```

Comment: TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: Does that error arise on the first or second line in the answer I posted?

Comment: The two lines are good. But when i tried to show subset, i got the error.

Comment: Can you show the original `vehicules` without errors?

Comment: I get 'Empty Dataframe' and my column names  as output when doing this (but I know there are some nulls in the column I check because I see them when doing `.head`